# Why is my new service script parameter ignored?

Tags: linux, bash, postgresql, init.d

I added an optional parameter to /etc/init.d/postgresql to specify a directory. If no directory is specified, the command is applied to all clusters.

Running the script in /etc/init.d executes all commands correctly:

```
cd /home/pi; clear # - omit
/etc/init.d/postgresql start
ps aux | grep pg

/etc/init.d/postgresql stop dev_5433
ps aux | grep pg # - stops only the dev_5433 cluster, all good
[dev_5433 cluster stopped, all good][2]
```

... but running the script as a service does not:

```
cd /home/pi; clear # - omit
/etc/init.d/postgresql start
ps aux | grep pg

service postgresql stop dev_5433
ps aux | grep pg # - stops all clusters, but should only stop the dev_5433 cluster
[Stops all clusters instead of only one][4]
```

Why does it seem to ignore my new parameter when I execute service commands?

Comment: Which specific Linux distro is this? `service` is a nonstandard command, and its implementations vary. (Also, just about all modern distros at this point have a preferred replacement for old SysV-style init scripts -- which is to say, you should probably be migrating to systemd or upstart or whatever else the local replacement happens to be, after which this would be more like `systemctl stop postgresql@dev_5433`).

Comment: ...this *isn't* a question that someone who's an expert in bash or an expert in PostgreSQL can answer without reading your specific distro's implementation of `service`. As such, the tags are arguably pulling in a whole bunch of folks who are very unlikely to be able to help you.

Comment: Linux distro: Raspbian (a fork of Debian, I believe)

Comment: My question was edited and my screenshots removed. I'm sure the editor meant well, but now my post is more difficult to follow.  I'll try to reword my question later.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557 (granted, asking specifically about code) for some background on why screenshots are frowned on. Short form: They're not searchable, they're not copy/pasteable, they make things harder for folks using screen readers or other assistive technologies (which can even just be high-contrast fonts), and they bitrot. If you could reproduce and copy/paste the content into the question as text, it'd be much appreciated.

Comment: (*Personally*, I'm a fan of [runit](http://smarden.org/runit/), which adopts the approach introduced by DJB daemontools -- in short, you have a directory for each service, and can run `sv d /service/postgresql*` to shut down all PostgreSQL instances, or `sv d /service/postgresql-dev_5433` to shut down just one of them. A runit init script is **far** simpler than a SysV init one -- see [the one for postgres](http://smarden.org/runit/runscripts.html#postgresql), which is three lines including the shebang).